# Combine 2 SQL Queries

Tags: oracle, condition

How do I combine these 2 queries?

```
select a, b, c from MY_TABLE where date < sysdate+1 AND c is NULL order by id

select a, b, c from MY_TABLE where date < sysdate AND b is NULL order by id
```

Comment: With a `UNION`? Or maybe with a `MINUS` or `INTERSECT` operator? Depends what you mean with "combine".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define "combine".  My guess is that you simply want to OR the predicates together

```
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE (dt_column < sysdate+1 and c IS NULL)
    OR (dt_column < sysdate and b IS NULL)
 ORDER BY id
```

You may, however, want to do something else.  Perhaps you want to `UNION ALL` the two result sets, for example, it order to get duplicate rows.